# On OS X 10.8, JDK7, fullscreen JFrame has an ugly white stripe at top

Tags: jframe, osx-lion, fullscreen, osx-mountain-lion

I am using the OS X Lion "native" utilities to send a JFrame to fullscreen mode. Namely, I'm using

```
import com.apple.eawt.*;
   ...
FullScreenUtilities.setWindowCanFullScreen(myJFrame, true);
   ...
Application.getApplication().requestToggleFullScreen(myJFrame);
```

This works very well except that an ugly white stripe appears at the top of the JFrame. The stripe appears to be the same size as the JFrame's title bar was, before we entered full screen mode, so I think it's probably caused by a mishandling of the title bar.

I tried calling

```
myJFrame.dispose();
myJFrame.setUndecorated(true);
myJFrame.show();
```

But this results in a weird fullscreen mode where the JFrame retains its original size, moves to the center and I get a grey cloth background.

What can I do to prevent the white stripe from appearing?